# Identify the edges of triangles in a network

Tags: r, igraph

In a triangle/circular graph of A->B->C. To reach C from A, A->C is shortest path but can also be reached if the path is part of triangle or circular path. Lets say if A->C is broken then C can be reached by A->B->C.I need an indicator saying about a backup paths.

How do I implement this, I tried using different commands in R but couldn't achieve and I am very new to R and igraph.

Comment: Is your graph directed or undirected?

Comment: Please add the code you are trying to make work to your question

Comment: Yes.. Its undirected graph

Answer (score 0):

Use `all_simple_paths()`

```
net <- data.frame(from= c('A', 'B', 'C', 'A'), 
                  to = c('B', 'C', 'E', 'C'), 
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

net <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(net)

igraph::all_simple_paths(net, 'A', 'C')
```

`igraph` is pretty powerful. It is definitely worth spending time and [exploring its documentation](http://igraph.org/r/). Also, Katherine Ognyanova created [an **AWESOME** tutorial](http://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph) that is definitely worth everyone's time.

Comment: I wasn't clear with my question. My graph is big and using simple path often takes lot of time and sometimes its infinite.

Comment: Can you please create a small example of the network you are using? Maybe you should filter out all the nodes and links you know you won't be traversing so your network is more manageable.